# Cannot Convert value of type (Product) -> [String :Any ] to specified type [ String : Any]

Tags: swift

This is my code :

```
private func CreateProductDictionaryForSale(prodToRegister: Product) -> [String : Any]
    {
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

        var dictionaryToReturn = CreateCommonProductDictionary(prodToRegister: prodToRegister)
        dictionaryToReturn["description"] = prodToRegister.m_Description
        dictionaryToReturn["location"] = prodToRegister.m_Location
        dictionaryToReturn["salesTime"] = prodToRegister.m_SaleTime
        dictionaryToReturn["userName"] = user?.displayName
        return dictionaryToReturn
    }
```

And this code calls it :

```
let thisProductToRegister: [String: Any] = CreateProductDictionaryForSale(prodToRegister)
```

Yet I get the error :

> let thisProductToRegister: [String: Any] = CreateProductDictionaryForSale(prodToRegister)

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Comment: Are you trying to call `CreateProductDictionaryForSale`? If yes, then you're not correctly calling it

Comment: Yes, I am calling it. What's wrong with this function calling ?

Comment: You don't pass the argument label. You should be calling it like this: `CreateProductDictionaryForSale(prodToRegister: myVar)`

Comment: BTW, the code doesn't seem to follow the Swift naming conventions, you might also want to address that.

Comment: Fixed, now I get error "Instance member 'CreateProductDictionaryForSale' cannot be used on type 'Product'"

Comment: Hope you're not trying to learn Swift through this question :). The error message is quite clear: you try to call an instance method from a static method, you need a `Product` instance for that.

Comment: Oh heck I forgot I made that function static !

Comment: (I've never used static functions before on Swift)

Comment: Please write an official answer so I can credit you! :)

Comment: It's unlikely this question will help other people, it's too localized. I'd prefer not to add an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution ended up that I forgot to call the method as static that it was, and use tags for arguments.